# How to present 3 types of Economic systems?

Tags: layout, user-expectation

I would like to build a 'homework-helping' community site, where students provide simple services for each other and earn a non-monetary form of credit (which I've called 'blue coins'). The purpose of this first system is to provide motivation for interaction (if a student collects blue coins then they can ask somebody else to do work for them i.e. spend their coins).

In addition to this form of economy (giving/receiving blue coins) I'd like to use the concept of 'gold coins': paid credit that can be used on professional services provided by teachers.  This is the second system and is a marketplace of services.

Finally, I'd like students to be able to subscribe, either monthly or yearly, to a 'Pro' account that will add benefits and also give them a certain amount of gold coins for free.

To me this seems like it could be a confusing system to the user.  Is there a precedent for using this type of system or should I try and simplify it?

(BTW, the 'homework-helping' context is contrived and is only for illustrative purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a million (or thereabouts) precedents and practices in this field... the processes of games in a Freemium market, wherein they use all 3 of these, almost all the time, for any game with any depth. If a game has gems, currency and social media connectivity, and is freemium, it's almost certainly milking all three of these as hard as it can.

Plus advertising perusing and reviews, and questionnaires/surveys, too.

Game monetisation is an art form, and there's much in the way of reports, insights and analysis of the balancing act of rewards, effort and payment economics. Sometimes dozens of these for a single game.